# Nested ng-app issue

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to utilize ng-app with in another ng-app. Separately both ng-app's are perform their function but as they come inside each other it creates an error.
for example

```
<body ng-app>
<div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
-----
</div>
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
........
</div>
</body>
```

On execution this give Error

> Argument 'MyCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

If any one have any solution for this issue, or have some other technique to solve this problem, please help me.

Comment: Just read the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp) _AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other._

Comment: There should be any solution for this problem... If yes, then please help me.

Answer (score 1):

**AngularJS applications cannot be nested within each other**. What you need to do is to design your modules in a way that such a thing is not needed. (eg. use nested controllers or split your app into separate modules)

Look into this topic from AngularJS website, it's explicitly mentioned that apps cannot be nested :

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp

To get a better sense about breaking an angular app into several modules take a look at these resources :

http://henriquat.re/modularizing-angularjs/modularizing-angular-applications/modularizing-angular-applications.html

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2014/03/27/13-step-guide-angularjs-modularization/

Answer (score 0):

There's only one ng-app allowed. There can be many **modules** it relies on.

Example:

```
//app.js
angular.module('app',['subApp'])
.run(() => { ... })

//meanwhile in subapp.js
angular.module('subapp', [])
.run(() => { ... })
```